# How to create a dynamic table when variable changes?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, filter

I am caught up understanding how to load a dynamic table, where the resulting array displayed in the dynamic table is filtered from a larger array.

**- the script doesn't run in JSFiddle, otherwise I would link an example -**

What happens currently, is with each button click the filtered array of results is pushed into the array which is used in the dynamic table. I can see the issue, which is using the **push()** method.

I am unable to tweak my syntax to perhaps instead of *pushing* the filtered results into the array, I need to be able to replace the entire array each time.

#### Code

```js
var chars = {
  [0671]: {
    tier: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    id: '7813',
  },
  [0748]: {
    tier: 1,
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    id: '5461',
  },
  [0478]: {
    tier: 2,
    name: 'Billy Bob',
    id: '8246',
  },
  [0475]: {
    tier: 2,
    name: 'Cindy Bob',
    id: '9634',
  },
};

//var tierChoice updates onclick, runs *result function*
var tierChoice = 1;

function tierSelect(tierVar) {
  tierChoice = tierVar;
  results();
}

//*result function* filters var chars, pushes into var results
var result = [];

function results() {
  for (var i in chars) {
    if (chars[i].tier == tierChoice) {
      result.push(chars[i]);
    }
  }
  charStats();
}

//*charStats function* creates a dynamic table, using a filtered array from var results
function charStats() {
  var buf = '';
  var header = '<tr><td width="100px">Name</td><td width="100px">ID</td></tr>';
  for (var i in result) {
    buf += '<tr>\n';
    buf += '<td>' + result[i].name + '</td>\n';
    buf += '<td>' + result[i].id + '</td>\n';
    buf += '</tr>\n';
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = header + buf;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Tier 1" onclick="tierSelect(1)"></input>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Tier 2" onClick="tierSelect(2)"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- dynamic table is HTML below -->
<table border="border:1px solid #fff" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0 auto" id="demo">
</table>
```

In short: Clicking on the first button should put John Doe and Jane Doe along with their ids into the result, clicking the second button should put Cindy Bob and Billy Bob along with their ids into the result, which is almost correctly done, but the problem is that these are appended to previous results, rather than overriding them.

Comment: *"the script doesn't run in JSFiddle"* why it doesn't run?

Comment: The script runs. Clicking the buttons produce rows. What is the expected output?

Comment: Hey Calvin, it may of been inexperience using it. When I put the data in, it kept coming up saying 'results() not defined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you just need to re-initialize `result` inside `results`:

```
function results() {
  result = [];
  for (var i in chars) {
    if (chars[i].tier == tierChoice) {
      result.push(chars[i]);
    }
  }
  charStats();
}
```

Also, you do not need to close `input` tags, since they are atomic, so change your HTML to

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Tier 1" onclick="tierSelect(1)">
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Tier 2" onClick="tierSelect(2)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/het26c1n/

Comment: Thank you for your help Lajos, confirmed that it works absolutely fine now when put into my original. Thank you additionally for the heads up with the tags, the little things do help in understanding how to clean up. Gave you a +1 but I'm under 15 rep.